# Calculate the scale of current Zoom Level with parameters like extent, resolution?

Tags: geoserver

I got the following parameters:

```
Width and height of Map: 450px, 560px

units : 'meters'

maxExtent : new OpenLayers.Bounds(806677.9759,802420.9858,8876817.5647,853497.8186405064)

resolutions: [199.51887828322785, 99.75943914161392, 49.87971957080696, 
24.93985978540348, 12.46992989270174, 6.23496494635087, 3.117482473175435, 
1.5587412365877176, 0.7793706182938588, 0.3896853091469294, 0.1948426545734647, 
0.09742132728673235, 0.048710663643366174, 0.024355331821683087, 0.012177665910841544,
0.006088832955420772, 0.003044416477710386, 0.001522208238855193]

numZoomLevels: 18

OpenLayers.DOTS_PER_INCH = 90.71428571428572;
```

Who inspire me how to calculate the scale of current Zoom Level?

Answer (score 16):

Map scale is defined as a ratio of `displayed units / measured units`.  Your specific case is a bit harder given that we have to traverse through two scales and two different units in order to arrive at the real world units.

Assuming horizontal scale is equivalent to vertical scale, we first look at the horizontal **pixel** resolution.  By this we're attempting to find the displayed units pixel:

```
scale = display / measured

      = feature / pixels

      = |(806677m - 876817m)| / 450px // I'm assuming you've made a typo with 8876817

      = 70140 / 450

      = 166.66 metres per pixel (inversely 0.006 pixels per metre)
```

Secondly, converting the pixel scale to find the **screen distance** per pixel:

```
      = real distance / pixel distance

      = 2.54cm (1 inch) / 90 pixels

      = 0.028 ~0.03
```

Bringing it all together:

```
   0.028 cm per pixel = 166.66 metres / x

   x * 0.028 = 166.66

   x = 166.66 / 0.028

   x = 5952.1
```

Therefore, your **map scale** is roughly 1:6000.

Comment: Greatly appreciated for your extremely detailed description. I will calculate it follow your way. Thanks.

Comment: No problem.  If you're calculating the scale repeatedly, you may want to condense the equation.  I've only layered it for you out of simplicity.

Comment: Haha, Yes! Actually, I want to know what the Zoom Level is for the scale value '1:3500'. Because some layer in my map display only when current scale is greater '1:3500'. BTW, I'm a new in GIS.

Comment: There is (of course) a strong dependence on getting the right pixel distance. So it won't be the same "scale" on your notebook and the attached projector.

Comment: There is a mistake in the answer of nagytech, because he compares m per pixel to cm per pixel! At first you have to convert the 0.028cm to meter! So you have 0.00028 meters and a scale of x = 166.66 / 0.00028 = 595214!

Answer (score 9):

There is a good information on Peter Robins [website](http://www.peterrobins.co.uk/it/olconcepts.html) which may help you easily with openlayers.

> To find the scale a resolution represents, you have to know how big a
>   pixel is; OL doesn't know that for sure, but makes some reasonable
>   assumptions. If you look at Util.js, and search for
>   getScaleFromResolution(), you will find that it uses 2 constants,
>   INCHES_PER_UNIT and DOTS_PER_INCH, and the calculation is "resolution
>   * OpenLayers.INCHES_PER_UNIT[units] * OpenLayers.DOTS_PER_INCH". For degrees this is resolution*4374754*72 (314,982,288), so the maximum
>   scale is 1:442,943,843. In metres, the maximum scale is
>   156543.0339*39.3701*72 (2,834.6472) or 1:443,744,273.

so the formule :

```
 map.getResolutions * OpenLayers.INCHES_PER_UNIT[units] * OpenLayers.DOTS_PER_INCH
```

i hope it helps you...

Comment: In **OpenLayers 2.14** `map.getResolutions` did not work for me, but getting the resolutions of the base layer did: `map.baseLayer.resolutions`. Keep in mind, however, this may result in more values than there are zoom levels...

Answer (score 0):

scale and zoom level can be convert by following table.

regardless of extend and resolution

https://developers.arcgis.com/documentation/mapping-apis-and-services/reference/zoom-levels-and-scale/

[image]

https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Zoom_levels

[image]