# Print Openlayers WMS map with fixed scaling

Tags: openlayers, wms, printing, scale, resolution

I need to print a map with a fixed scale (1:500 and 1:1000) on A4. The online map is done with *Openlayers*, the print request is sent to *QGIS Server* using ***WMS getPrint*** function.

I mange to get an approximate scale of around 1:500 (1:594 horizontally and 1:554 vertically), but I can't figure out how to fix my formulas to get an exact solution. The formula I use to calculate the extent in meters is:

```
extent_width = width*printResolution/screenScale
extent_height = height*printResolution/screenScale
```

To calculate *printResolution* in m/px I use an approach described in [this post](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/158435/how-to-get-current-scale-in-openlayers-3#answer-158518):

```
  function printResolution(scale) {
    var unit = map.getView().getProjection().getUnits();
    var inchesPerMetre = 39.3700787;
    var dpi = 120;

    return scale / (ol.proj.Units.METERS_PER_UNIT[unit] * inchesPerMetre * dpi);
  }
```

To calculate the actual *screenScale* I use the approach described in [this post](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/242424/how-to-get-map-units-to-find-current-scale-in-openlayers):

```
  function screenScale() {
    var unit = map.getView().getProjection().getUnits();
    var resolution = map.getView().getResolution();
    var inchesPerMetre = 39.3700787;
    var dpi = 96;

    return resolution * ol.proj.Units.METERS_PER_UNIT[unit] * inchesPerMetre * dpi;
  }
```

And finally I put it together calculation the size of the print box on screen using:

```
  var w = Number(size[0])*printResolution(scale)/screenScale()*18000;
  var h = Number(size[1])*printResolution(scale)/screenScale()*18000;

  var bounds = map.getView().calculateExtent([w,h]);
  var printBox = [
    [bounds[0], bounds[1]],
    [bounds[0], bounds[3]],
    [bounds[2], bounds[3]],
    [bounds[2], bounds[1]],
    [bounds[0], bounds[1]]
  ];
```

So I'm aware of errors in the calculation (as I have to multiply by 18000 to get an approximate scaling), but I can't figure out what is wrong.

Here is the complete code in a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/geraldo/cyxkev9r/) showing the described behavior.

PS: This is a follow up to [this question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/300667/how-to-get-extent-from-current-resolution-in-openlayers-3-for-printing) posted some time ago.

Comment: Maybe this OpenLayers example can be of some help to you: https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/export-pdf.html

Comment: Thanks, I had a look on that. My problem is how to get the scaling into the width and height calculation.